How to project an intersection shape in a 3D set of surfaces
I need to get a intersection curve on the bottom of the 3D shape generated below:
f[a_, b_, c_, x1_, x2_] := Exp[a x1 + b x2 + c x1 x2]
c = .7
Show[Plot3D[f[a, b, c, -1, -1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
Plot3D[f[a, b, c, -1, 1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
Plot3D[f[a, b, c, 1, -1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
Plot3D[f[a, b, c, 1, 1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]]


I highlighted the desired curves in blue.
I have tried using ContourPlot3D but it just outputs an empty cell. I can do just ContourPlot and get the family of lines, but this way I get extra.
Show[ContourPlot[
f[a, b, c, -1, -1] == f[a, b, c, -1, 1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
ContourPlot[
f[a, b, c, -1, -1] == f[a, b, c, 1, 1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
ContourPlot[
f[a, b, c, -1, -1] == f[a, b, c, 1, -1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
ContourPlot[
f[a, b, c, 1, 1] == f[a, b, c, 1, -1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
ContourPlot[
f[a, b, c, 1, 1] == f[a, b, c, -1, 1], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]]


I do not want to play tricks with changing domains manually. I want it to be a straightforward result of plotting the intersections in the bottom of the bawl formed by 4 surfaces. Thanks in advance for any help.

There are 6 lines. funs = {f[a, b, c, -1, -1], f[a, b, c, -1, 1], f[a, b, c, 1, 1],     f[a, b, c, 1, -1]}; ContourPlot[#1 == #2, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}] & @@@    Subsets[funs, {2}] // Show  And I think you want to plot Plot3D[Max[funs], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]

@cvgmt
Yeah, that would work! Thank you!


four surfaces intersect to each other.

f[a_, b_, c_, x1_, x2_] := Exp[a  x1 + b  x2 + c  x1  x2]
c = .7;
funs = {f[a, b, c, -1, -1], f[a, b, c, -1, 1], f[a, b, c, 1, 1], 
  f[a, b, c, 1, -1]}; 
ContourPlot[#1 == #2, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}] & @@@ 
  Subsets[funs, {2}] // Show



The top intersections : 2D graphics

ContourPlot[Max[funs], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> All, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]



The top intersections : 3D graphics

Plot3D[Max[funs], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red, 
 PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, ClippingStyle -> None]



Thank you! This is very helpful!
